# Configuring Oracle Apex 22.2 email using Office 365

Tags: smtp, office365, oracle-apex

I'm trying to configure Oracle Apex 22.2 email to use Office 365 as the SMTP server, but am getting an error "ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available".

I've ensured that UTL_SMTP and UTL_TCP have been granted execute to the APEX_220200 user.

I'm using the following settings per the Microsoft website:
SMTP host address: smtp.office365.com
SMTP host port: 586
SMTP authentication username: my MS admin account username
SMTP password: my MS admin account password
Use SSL/TLS: After connection is established (sends StartTLS per Oracle documentation)

When I set SSL/TLS to either 'Yes' or 'No', I do not get an error but no messages are sent.

I've searched for configuration options I may have missed, and have found a couple of utilities to help verify that the settings above seem to work when using the UTL_SMTP package.

Has anyone else experienced this situation? What steps have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did is ok. Now you have to download de https certificate from office365 web site and use it to create an oracle wallet. Then, you must configure the Wallet Path in the Apex Instance Setting (workspace INTERNAL).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).